# CPU compatibility with GA-78LMT-S2P

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I've been considering upgrading my CPU (currently an AMD FX-4100), but I'm a little unsure how I can identify which models will be compatible with my motherboard ([GIGABYTE GA-78LMT-S2P, rev 5.0](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4125#sp)).

Having checked the GIGABYTE website, I managed to find this chart of compatible CPUs:
http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=4125

However, I still have some questions.

1. Am I right in thinking that no Intel CPUs are listed because motherboards are limited to *either* Intel *or* AMD, and the one I have happens to be AMD? Or is it more of a marketing thing where GIGABYTE would rather you bought from AMD rather Intel? (I assume it's the former, but I just want to be clear)
2. Is this list as restrictive as it might suggest? E.g. an FX-8140 would work but an FX-8150 would not, or an FX-8300 would work but an FX-8320 would not, etc.

Comment: The listed supported CPUs is right on the [products website](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=4125). You have an AMD motherboard, only AMD x86-64 processors will work, but thats sort of a given.  **If a FX-8150 is the same socket as a FX-8140 then it would work.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any CPU's listed on that list will work with that motherboard along with any other AMD CPU with AM3 or AM3+ socket. Since that motherboard was released 18 to 24 months ago and the latest stable BIOS driver was released 6 months ago, they probably just haven't updated the CPU support list to include the latest AMD CPU's.

To answer your questions too:

1. Only AMD CPU's will work with that motherboard. AMD and Intel CPU's are very different in in many aspects which include placement of their pins. Motherboard manufacturers have to design their board around a certain socket type (AM3+ in your case) and only CPU's which fit that socket will work with that motherboard.
2. This I answered above too. This motherboard is a couple of years old so they may not have updated the CPU support list to include any recent CPU's that have been released. For the most part, any CPU with a AM3 or AM3+ socket will work with this motherboard.